# Where's Offset Edge Slide in Blender 2.80 menus?

Tags: interface

In order to learn Blender I'm thoroughly reading the docs and I've come across [Offset Edge Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html#offset-edge-slide), which is barely documented but seems really useful to add detail in a face.

Problem is, I cannot find it in the menus of Blender 2.80. Granted I can use the shortcut or the F3 search tool, but it'd be great to know whether it appears in a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the *Offset Edge Loop Cut/Slide* in the toolbar. You need to press and hold your left mouse button on the *Loop Cut* icon and then select the *Offset Edge Loop Cut* from the menu. The naming is a bit inconsistent, the menu entry says *Cut* and the description, documentation and last operation panel call it *Slide*.

[image: Offset Edge Loop Cut]

[image: Operator in action]